# How to create multilingual web pages with fastapi-babel?

Tags: python, fastapi, gettext

I'm thinking of creating a multilingual web page with [fastapi-babel](https://github.com/Anbarryprojects/fastapi-babel).

I have configured according to the [documentation](https://github.com/Anbarryprojects/fastapi-babel).
The translation from English to French was successful.
However, I created a .po file for another language, translated it, compiled it, but the translated text does not apply.

```
from fastapi_babel import _
from fastapi_babel.middleware import InternationalizationMiddleware as I18nMiddleware
from fastapi_babel import Babel
from fastapi_babel import BabelConfigs

configs = BabelConfigs(
     ROOT_DIR=__file__,
     BABEL_DEFAULT_LOCALE="en",
     BABEL_TRANSLATION_DIRECTORY="lang",
)
logger.info(f"configs: {configs.__dict__}")
babel = babel(configs)
babel.install_jinja(templates)

app.add_middleware(I18nMiddleware, babel=babel)


@app.get("/items/{id}", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def read_item(request: Request, id: str):
     babel.locale = "en"
     logger.info(_("Hello World"))
     babel. locale = "fa"
     logger.info(_("Hello World"))
     babel.locale = "ja"
     logger.info(_("Hello World"))
     return templates.TemplateResponse('item.html', {'request': request, 'id': id})
```

Above, the result will be:

```
INFO: Hello World
INFO: Bonjour le monde
INFO: Hello World
```

How can the translation be applied to languages other than French?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the old version `0.0.3`.
When I changed the version to the latest `0.0.8`, the translation was reflected in languages other than French.

```
pip install fastapi-babel==0.0.8
```

### Note

You need restart FastAPI server, after `pybabel compile -d lang`

If `BABEL_DEFAULT_LOCALE` and `babel.locale` is same, it doesn't translate.

```
babel = Babel(
    configs=BabelConfigs(
        ROOT_DIR=__file__,
        BABEL_DEFAULT_LOCALE="en",
        BABEL_TRANSLATION_DIRECTORY="lang",
    )
)
```

```
babel.locale = "en"
```

#### When you update translation files.

Run this 2 commands.

1. `pybabel extract -F babel.cfg -o messages.pot .`
2. `pybabel compile -d lang`

Please don't run this command after you create .po file.

`pybabel init -i messages.pot -d lang -l fa`

If you run, your po file will be reset. (Delete all your translations.)